# How to reference an external workbook through VBA Formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to create a macro that opens and edits an external workbook.
Sheet is open(wb). I am looking for a cell (C2) from sheetName1 into another sheet from same wb (sheetName2) and return a specific column.
Macro is written into a separate workbook. Formula should be filled down

my code:

```
wb.Sheets(sheetName1).Range(O2:O2000).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C2, 'filePath[fileName.xlsx]sheetName2'!(A:D),3,False)"
```

when I run the code, get an application defined or object defined error

Comment: Can you produce a more meaningful example? The purpose of VLOOKUP is to look in column `1` but surely not to return what's in column `1`. How did you come up with `(""A:D"")`? That can't work, replace it with `A:D`. Usually, the worksheet name is also included in the single quotes `'...'!...`. Please explain if the external workbook is open or if it needs to be opened and what the formula is supposed to look up. Add the information to your post. Use simple words.

Comment: Just `A:D` without the parentheses.